# CSS Table with custom borders

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with a simple table design as i'm from backend I need a table like this

[image]

What I have right now

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 100%;
}
tr { 
 border: none; 
}
.first{
    width: 40%;
    font-family: Quasimoda;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #1D1D1E;
}
.middle{
    width: 60%;
    font-family: Quasimoda;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #1D1D1E;
}
.last{
    width: 40%;
    font-family: Quasimoda;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #1D1D1E;
}
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  
  <tr>
    <td class="University">January</td>
    <td class="middle ">the progress bar will be placed here </td>
    <td class="last">870</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first">January</td>
    <td class="middle ">the progress bar will be placed here </td>
    <td class="last">560</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please help. I have tried with multiple html table attributes all gone in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `thead tr` element bottom border, and the right border of the `.first` element:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Quasimoda;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #1D1D1E;
}

.first {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.middle {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Unique values:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first">January</td>
      <td class="middle ">the progress bar will be placed here </td>
      <td class="last">870</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="first">January</td>
      <td class="middle ">the progress bar will be placed here </td>
      <td class="last">560</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thankyou @Ori Drori you are my bro I was struggling like anything from hrs

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your picture is not that clear.
I was not clear where you want border actually.
But I try to do this, Run the code snippet and have a look, and let me know if this works for you or not.

```css
.colspan2border
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.rightBorder
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.pr-left1
{
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
table 
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr 
{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr colspan="2" class='colspan2border'><td>Unique values:</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rightBorder pr-left1">University</td>
    <td>870</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rightBorder pr-left1">Custom</td>
    <td>560</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```